# How to get the title and description of a hyperlink that is converted from plaintext?

Tags: php, curl

I have within my application a function to change plain text url's into hyperlinks. The function is below.

```
$rexProtocol = '(https?://)?';
$rexDomain   = '((?:[-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}\.)+[-a-zA-Z0-9]{2,63}|(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})';
$rexPort     = '(:[0-9]{1,5})?';
$rexPath     = '(/[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]*?)?';
$rexQuery    = '(\?[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?';
$rexFragment = '(#[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?';

// Solution 1:

    function callback($match)
    {
        // Prepend http:// if no protocol specified
        $completeUrl = $match[1] ? $match[0] : "http://{$match[0]}";
        $html = file_get_contents_curl($completeUrl);

        //parsing begins here:


$doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($html);
        $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

        //get and display what you need:
        $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

        for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
        {
            $meta = $metas->item($i);
            if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
                $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
            if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
                $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        }
        $posted2 = "<h3>$title</h3><br>".$description."<a href='$completeUrl'>View page</a>";
        $type = "View URL summary";
        return '<a href="' . $completeUrl . '">'
            . $completeUrl . '</a>';
    }

echo $posted2;
$posted = preg_replace_callback("&\\b$rexProtocol$rexDomain$rexPort$rexPath$rexQuery$rexFragment(?=[?.!,;:\"]?(\s|$))&",
    'callback', $posted);
```

What I want to happen is `$posted2` contain the title and description of the URL being checked. However when I echo $posted2 it is blank, even though I defined it within the function callback. So I ask if there is an alternative method I can use so that when an Url is found within the comment it is changed into a hyperlink and the title and description are added to the variable $posted2. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you defined `$posted2` within the function but (due to your incorrect indenting) you try to echo it after.

Comment: yes but why is $posted2 not working outside of the function @kingkero

Comment: Because it hasn't been defined outside the function, see [variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more information

Comment: how can I make it defined outside of the function? or is that not possible

Comment: It is and when you follow my posted link there are possibilites. But usually that is not a good practice and there are other solutions available. However without further information, e.g. why you need it outside the function, I cannot help you

Comment: @kingkero I need $posted2 outside of the function because I need to insert it into the database